# How find the $AP+\frac{1}{2}BP$ minmum value

Tags: geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

An equilateral triangle $ABC$ such $$AB=BC=AC=2a>0$$
 A circle $O$ is inscribed in triangle $ABC$,and the point $P$ on the circle $O$.

Find the minimum $$AP+\dfrac{1}{2}BP$$

My idea: let $$A(-a,0),B(a,0),O(0,\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}a)$$
then the circle equation is $$
x^2+(y-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{6})^2=\dfrac{1}{12}a^2$$
let $P(x,y)\;$ , then
$$|PA|+\dfrac{1}{2}|PB|=\sqrt{(x+a)^2+y^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}$$
where $$
x^2+(y-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}a}{6})^2=\dfrac{1}{12}a^2$$
then I can't.Thank you [image]

Comment: You're apparently trying to use analytic geometry and placing the triangle in such a way that $\;AB\;$ is on the $\;x$-axis and the origin at the middle point of this side. Then, $\;O\;$ is the intersection of the medians and it's thus at one third of its length from the origin. Since its length (or *any* height's length in an equilateral triangle) is $\;\frac{\sqrt3}2a\;$ , the point $\;O\;$ is at the point $\;\left(0\,,\,\frac{\sqrt3}{3\cdot 2}a\right)\;$ , so I think *your* point $\;O\;$ is off by a factor $\;\frac12\;$ ...

Comment: Oh,@DonAntonio,Thank you very much

Comment: have you already studied Lagrange's Multipliers ?

Comment: @DonAntonio,I konw this methods,But This problem is Junior high school students
ask me.Thank you

Comment: Junior high schools maximum/minimum problems? Unless some quadratic (parabola) kicks in somewhere (and I can't see where), I can't see how a *standard* junior h.s. student can cope with this...

Comment: In china,Especially in Shanghai  some  junior hight schools have learned the knowledge of high school math competition

Comment: Still, no multipliers? Then susbtitution is the way and a really terrible-looking equation...unless there's some slick trick somewhere, of course. Good luck!

Comment: @DonAntonio,Thank you,+1

Comment: What about a geometrical-intuitive proof? Look at the triangle $\;\Delta APB\;$ . As the sum of any two sides of a triangle is always bigger than the third side, we get $\;|AP|+|PB|\ge AB=2a\;$. Now, "sliding" $\;P\;$ towards the lower tangency point, we get that $\;|AP|+\frac12|PB|\;$ approaches $\;\frac12a+\frac12\frac a2=\frac34a\;$ , and no other triangle formed with such three points $\;A,B,P\;$ will have a smaller length, so the answer seems to be $\;\frac 34a\;$...

Comment: @DonAntonio I've been working on a geometric proof, and just by playing around with $P$ I've determined that its between $0.66a$ and $0.67a$.

Comment: @DonAntonio ah, I just realized your triangle ABC has side length $2a$. In my comment to you above, I'm assuming a ABC has side length $a$, so bear that in mind.

Comment: Good point, @David: **I**  forgot about that and my last comment assumed the sides' length is $\;a\;$ ...:) . Correcting, I think the minimum is $$\frac122a+\frac12a=\frac32a$$ pretty close to what you say assuming $\;2a\;$ instead of $\;a\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I now think the minimum is $\frac{\sqrt7}{2}a$, in case you're still curious.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I can't manage English well, so I might just use the google translate.

Take $B$'s inverse points about the circle, and call it $B'$.

By conclusions concerning Apollonian circles, we knew that $PB'=\dfrac{1}{2}PB$.

Hence we only need to determine the minimum of $PA+PB'$, thus it's easy to observe that when $P$ lies on the line $AB$ we get the minimum value, and that is quite easy to calculate.

The answer is $\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}{2}a$, if I'm not mistaken.（which happens a lot)

Comment: BTW,if you can read Chinese you can visit my blog to obtain more details about the proof:http://graphbuster.com/?p=938

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

Taking it from where you left it and correcting the coordinates of $\;O\;$ , we get the circle's equation is

$$x^2+\left(y-\frac a{2\sqrt3}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{12}\;\;\;\;(I)$$

Observe that since the $\;x$-axis is tangent to the circle, the absolute value of the center's $\;y$-coordinate  equals the circle's radius...

Now, with your notation

$$|PA|+\frac12|PB|=\sqrt{(x+a)^2+y^2}+\frac12\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}\;\;\;\;(II)$$

Thus, we want to minimize (II) contiioned to (I) , and thus Lagrange's Multipliers may help here...or

$$(I)\implies x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{12}-\left(y-\frac a{2\sqrt3}\right)^2}$$

and substitute in (II) to have a one-variable extrema problem (first derivative and stuff)

Comment: maybe this follow the equation is very ugly? Thank you

Comment: Yes, it looks really, really ugly....

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Omri Nissan Solan.

Let $K$ and $L$ be common points of the circle with $AB$ and $BC$ respectively

and let $BO\cap KL=\{M\}$.

Thus, our circle it's the Apollonian circle of $\Delta KLB$.

Id est, $AP+\frac{1}{2}PB=AP+PM\geq AM=\frac{a\sqrt7}{2}$.